# C# - Why is it possible for a readonly dictionary to "set"?

Tags: c#

Apologies first for the image.  I don't have the source.

My question is why is it possible to "set" a readonly dictionary (last line of the program) ?  What's the difference if the dictionary is NOT declared as readonly ?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You are not setting the dictionary, you are setting something inside the dictionary.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: _"Apologies first for the image. I don't have the source."_ How did you get the image?

Comment: You could declare the dictionary as `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>` because a regular dictionary already implements it: `IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();`. On that way you can't modify it (easily).

Comment: @Progman Apologies.  I will refrain from doing that in the future.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Was watching a video when I came across it.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ic.  So there are mutable dictionary and immutable IReadOnlyDictionary.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that your dictionary is not read only. It is a "regular" dictionary with all its functionality. What is read only is the field `_dictionary` which holds a reference to the actual Dictionary. Therefore, you cannot replace the dictionary assigned to `_dictionary`.

Answer (score 4):

Because "readonly" here is field _dictionary itself. But Dictionary class is mutable and you still can change internal values.